# Story revolving around a sarcophagus which eats its inhabitants slowly while keeping them alive

Tags: story-identification, horror, wizards

I am looking for a short horror/fantasy story about a wizard (?) who owns a sarcophagus which eats its inhabitants slowly but keeps them alive. First your skin would be eaten, than the muscles and so on. The inhabitant would be awake and suffering all the time. If the inhabitant is freed after some time, he would still be alive even as a skeleton. At the end the son (or maybe apprentice) of the owner ended in the sarcophagus, either by accident or as the result of a plot of some third party involved.

- I have read the story a few years ago and I think it was quite new at this time.
- There was an explanation in the story that sarcophagus actually translates as "meat eater".
- I am quite sure that the sarcophagus was located in the home of the owner.
- Not sure about this one: the owner had a skeleton servant who has been in the sarcophagus.

*Update*

- The story was written in English.
- I have read it in a magazine.
- If I had to guess, it was written around 2010.

Comment: https://www.ancient-origins.net/news-history-archaeology/unravelling-mystery-flesh-eating-sarcophagi-assos-001813

Comment: @Spencer - indeed. Which makes identifying this story all the more problematical

Comment: What time did you read this? In a magazine, an anthology, or online? In what language? When do you guess the story was written?

Comment: @Spencer I updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story is "Mr Gaunt" by John Langan

Available in the print collection *New Cthulhu: the Recent Weird and Mr. Gaunt and Other Uneasy Encounters*

Found online [here](https://pstdarkness.com/2016/07/14/mr-gaunt-by-john-langan/):

> Once they were in the study, Gaunt wasted no time, making straight for the great stone sarcophagus.  Peter screamed with all the force he could muster, calling for help from anyone who could hear him, then wailing in pure animal terror.  The skeleton made no effort to silence him.  At the sarcophagus with its furious visage, Gaunt brought his stark face down to Peter’s a second time, as if for a last look at him.  He heard that faint whisper again, what sounded like the driest of chuckles.  Then it reached out and slid the massive stone lid open with one spindly arm.  The odor of decay, the ripe stench of a dead deer left at the side of the road for too many hot days, filled the room.  Gagging, Peter saw that the interior of the sarcophagus was curiously rough, not with the roughness of, say, sandstone,  but with a deliberate roughness, as if the stone had been painstakingly carved into row upon row of small sharp points, like teeth.  The skeleton flung him into that smell, against those points.  Before he could make a final, futile gesture of escape, the lid closed and Peter was in darkness, swathed in the thick smell of rot, his last sight the skeleton’s idiot grin.  Nor was that the worst.  He had been in the stone box only a few seconds, though doubtless it seemed an eternity, when the stone against which he was leaning grew warm.  As it warmed, it shifted, the way the hide of an animal awakening from a deep sleep twitches.  Peter jerked away from the rough stone, his heart in his throat as movement rippled through the coffin’s interior.  If he could have been fortunate, his terror would have jolted him into unconsciousness, but I know this was not the case.  If he was unlucky, as I know he was, he felt the sides of the sarcophagus abruptly swell toward him, felt the rows of sharp points press against him, lightly at first, then more insistently, then more insistently still, until—
>
> I’ve mentioned the root of the word “sarcophagus;” it was Peter, ironically enough, who told it to me.  It’s Greek:  it means “flesh eating.”  Exactly how that word came to be applied to large stone coffins I’m unsure, but in this case it was quite literally true.  Peter was enclosed within a kind of mouth, a great stone mouth, and it…consumed him.  The process was not quick.  By the time George returned to the house almost a week and a half later, however, it was complete.  Sometime in the long excruciation before that point, Peter must have realized that his father was implicated in what was happening to him.  It was impossible for him not to be.  His father had brought Mr. Gaunt into the house, and then left Peter at his mercy.  His beloved father had failed, and his failure was Peter’s death.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should include some relevant quotes from the link so that this answer is still useful if the link disappears.

Comment: @Bioman35353 Thank you very much! After all my fruitless questions, finally one gets an answer!